# Drupal 7 hook_form_alter and submitting the form

Tags: forms

I added some custom field so that i can get more information when someone registers into the website but i want to alter one field on the form. I created a module which has a hook_form_alter function so that i can alter the field_first_name of the registration form. here is the code

```
function user_registration_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
if ($form_id == 'user_register_form'){

    $form['field_first_name'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => t('First Name'),
        '#description' => t('Enter your first name.'),
        '#maxlength' => 255,
        '#required' => TRUE,
        );



}
if (isset($form['actions']['submit'])) {
 $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] ='user_registration_form_submit';
   }

}
```

I also created a the function which handles the form submission.

```
function user_registration_form_submit(&$form, &$form_state)
{


$fe_id = db_insert('field_revision_field_first_name')
    ->fields(array(
        'field_first_name_value' => $form_state['value']['field_first_name'],
        ))->execute();
    drupal_set_message(t('your form entry has been added'));
}
```

My problem is that when i submit the form and i check the user details. i find that the first name details does not exist in the database or when i login as the administrator and click on the 'people' link. i find that all information is are submitted except the first name field which i am trying to alter. I also tried to submit the form without the form submit function but it still doesn't work.

and i get the following error message if i add the form_submit function

> Notice: Undefined index: value in user_registration_form_submit() (line 37 of /var/www/html/lite/sites/all/modules/user_regestration/user_registration.module).
>
> PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'entity_id'
>   doesn't have a default value: INSERT INTO
>   {field_revision_field_first_name} (field_first_name_value) VALUES
>   (:db_insert_placeholder_0); Array ( [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => ) in
>   user_registration_form_submit() (line 38 of
>   /var/www/html/lite/sites/all/modules/user_regestration/user_registration.module).

THIS IS LINE 37 AND 38 OF MY CODE

```
'field_first_name_value' => $form_state['value']['field_first_name'],
))->execute();
```

I am creating the module on localhost first before i push it to the live website

Comment: the second question is answered here http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/204068/how-do-i-programmatically-insert-the-entity-id or here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37798980/drupal-7-hook-form-alter-and-submitting-the-form/37822904#37822904 ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a typo, change value to **values**

To get the user id use:

```
<?php
global $user;
print $user->uid;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for that correction but know the error has changed and its as follows ................."PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'entity_id' doesn't have a default value: INSERT INTO {field_revision_field_first_name} (field_first_name_value) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0); Array ( [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => john ) in user_registration_form_submit() (line 38 of /var/www/html/lite/sites/all/modules/user_regestration/user_registration.module)."

Comment: so - what entity are you trying to insert ? a field revision ???? something seems strange to me here ..

Comment: I looked into my database and found that drupal had made a table for the field first_name so i want to insert data into the first_name field but drupal is giving me an error of entity_id does not have a default value. the entity_id field is in that table.

Comment: the entity in this case refers to the user. so the entity_id will be the userid, see my edit to get the current user's id

Comment: It could be that the user is not created in your hook ...

Comment: thanks but now i am trying to figure out how do i generate the user_id so that it can be inserted into the entity_id field.

Comment: actually this is another question. maybe [profile2](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2) will help you. if you want to do it yourself, add another question !