# How do I programmatically insert the entity ID?

Tags: 7, database, forms

I have added extra fields on the drupal 7 user registration form and created a module with a hook_form_alter function so that i can alter one field in the registration form. 
in the same file i also added the hook_form_submit function to handle the submission of that input box.

```
function user_registration_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
if ($form_id == 'user_register_form'){

    $form['field_first_name'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => t('First Name'),
        '#description' => t('Enter your first name.'),
        '#maxlength' => 255,
        '#required' => TRUE,
        );


}

if (isset($form['actions']['submit'])) {
        $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'user_registration_form_submit';
       }
}


function user_registration_form_submit(&$form, &$form_state)
    {
        $fe_id = db_insert('field_revision_field_first_name')
        ->fields(array(
            'field_first_name_value' => $form_state['values']['field_first_name'],
            ))->execute();
        drupal_set_message(t('your form entry has been added'));
    }
```

When i click on the submit button i get the following error message

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'entity_id' doesn't have a default value: INSERT INTO {field_revision_field_first_name} (field_first_name_value) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0); Array ( [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => john ) in user_registration_form_submit() (line 38 of /var/www/html/lite/sites/all/modules/user_regestration/user_registration.module)‌​‌​

I noticed the error is generated because the"entity_id doesn't have a default value" when the insert query is executed. 
My question is how do i include the entity_id default value.

Comment: here entity id is user id, get uid from $form_state

Comment: I am new to module development in drupal. how can I get the uid when i am registering user.

Comment: do you use devel module to debug? if yes dpm($form_state); you will get full structure of $form_state array variable in hook_submit($f, $f). simply you need to install devel module, contains mainy debug function use dpm($var) to get printed whole variable after page reload, or you can use watchdog(); too. google for watchdog debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use a module providing this functionality, like [profile2](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2) ?

The user is not created in your submithandler, so either you save it:

```
function foo_user_register_form_submit($form, &$form_state){
    $edit = array(
          'name' => $form_state['values']['name'], 
          'pass' => user_password(),
          'mail' => $form_state['values']['mail'],
          'init' => $form_state['values']['mail'], 
          'status' => 1, 
          'access' => REQUEST_TIME,
          'field_first_name' => array(LANGUAGE_NONE => array(array('value' => $form_state['values']['field_first_name']))),
    );
    user_save(drupal_anonymous_user(), $edit);
}
```

For more details see the [docs](https://www.drupal.org/node/1063598).

Or you could try to add a custom submit handler, which would be fired after the user is created, in form_alter:

```
$form['#submit'][] = 'your_custom_submit_handler_function';
```

In there the user should already be created. so:

```
function your_custom_submit_handler_function(&$form, &$form_state)
    {
        $fe_id = db_insert('field_revision_field_first_name')
        ->fields(array(
            'field_first_name_value' => $form_state['values']['field_first_name'],
            ))->execute();
        drupal_set_message(t('your form entry has been added'));
    }
```

> But keep in mind, that this custom inserting maybe needs some more
>   code, here you only add the revision entry ..

Comment: Thank you very much. The first solution worked and it was exactly what i was looking for.